# Как выбрать все заказы пользователя Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Как выбрать все заказы пользователя с ид 12 за февраль? По идеи это делается через АПИ. Кто нибуть подскажите.

Comment: в документации же всё есть да ещё и с примерами

Comment: а можно пример, а то всё в доке есть а прислать пример кода не можете

Answer (score 0):

В первом же примере из документации CSaleOrder::GetList вставляем в фильтр нужный ID пользователя.

```
<?
// Выведем даты всех заказов текущего пользователя за текущий месяц, отсортированные по дате заказа
$arFilter = Array(
   "USER_ID" => 12,
   ">=DATE_INSERT" => date($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("SHORT")), mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), 1, date("Y")))
   );

$db_sales = CSaleOrder::GetList(array("DATE_INSERT" => "ASC"), $arFilter);
while ($ar_sales = $db_sales->Fetch())
{
   echo $ar_sales["DATE_INSERT_FORMAT"]."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: а не подскажите, как для конкретного пользователя добавить скидку?